# How to Login to VSTS programmatically

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

I have an automatic branching utility that does various operations.
We have upgraded to VSTS and I am having trouble using the Tfs calls with the new server:

```
//login

NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("emailAddress", password");

BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(netCred);

TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);

tfsCred.AllowInteractive = false;

TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsServer = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://myco.visualstudio.com/mycoll"), tfsCred);

// get a local workspace

VersionControlServer sc = server.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;

... other code
```

and then boom!
"You are not authorized to access https://myco.visualstudio.com/mycoll"

Is there some setting somewhere?

Should I try and use the REST API?

Am I calling something I shouldn't?

I've tried all sorts of formats for the URI, with :8080, with /tfs in the path to no avail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PAT (Personal Access Token) to access VSTS. Click on your profile in VSTS and go to security menu item. You can define a PAT in there. Keep the PAT saved as it will only be shown once.

[image]

Define the scope as per your needs 
[image]

You can use the PAT to access TFS REST API as shown in following PowerShell sample. Using https://yourAccount.visualstudio.com or https://yourAccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection for ColletionUri parameter is OK.

```html
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $token,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $collectionUri
)



$User=""

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User,$token)));
$header = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)};

$Uri = $collectionUri + '/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0'

$projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $Uri -Headers $header
```

You can find C# code samples here https://www.domstamand.com/accessing-tfs-2017-programmatically/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
That will prove useful.
Is it me or is this API usage stuff making things harder.
I'll get used to it  :)